# Unable to make Cloudant query on IBM Bluemix

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloudant

**Issue:**

I am trying to sort the result by a Date object. But this error was thrown.

```
"reason": "Unspecified or ambiguous sort type. Try appending :number or :string to the sort field. createdAt"
```

I tried appending `:string` to the sort field in the query json but it did not work.

Is there a way to sort by Date object? Alternatively, what is a proper way to stringify the date object for sorting?

**The Date Object**

The date object looks like this: `"createdAt": "2018-05-03T08:29:53.875Z"`

**The action I ran**

```
function main(params) {
    if (!params.fieldA) {
    return Promise.reject({ error: 'no fieldA specified'});
  }

  return {
    query: {
        "selector": {
            "fieldA": params. fieldA
        },
        "fields": [
          "_id",
          "fieldA",
          "fieldB",
          "rate",
          "createdAt"
        ],
        "sort": [
            {
                "createdAt": "desc"
            }
        ],
        "limit": 1 // only return the latest entry
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: What is your command/code?

Comment: @user3405291Added the command

Comment: I now have a workaround - convert the date to unix timestamp, sort it by "createdAt":number : "desc"